# Handling parameterization in SystemVerilog packages

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

SystemVerilog added packages to provide namespaces for common code pieces (functions, types, constants, etc).  But since packages are not instantiated, they cannot be parameterized, so dealing with parameterized members is problematic.  In practice I have found this pretty limiting since very often my custom types have some parameters dictating field widths etc.

I generally deal with this by using parameters with default values and just understanding that I will need to go back change the package source code for some applications, which seems very wrong to me.  But i have yet to find a way to handle this more cleanly.  For example:

```
package my_pkg;
    parameter ADDR_MSB = 7;
    parameter DATA_MSB = 31;

    typedef struct {
        logic [ADDR_MSB:0] address;
        logic [DATA_MSB:0] data;
    } simple_struct_t;

endpackage
```

Has anyone found a cleaner way of dealing with this?  I'd love to hear about it since I think packages are a very powerful addition to SV enabling safer code reuse, but this limitation is pretty severe.

Answer (score 5):

You could use parameterized macros to name a type with particular widths:

```
`define SIMPLE_STRUCT(NAME) \
   simple_struct_t_``NAME``

`define SIMPLE_STRUCT_DEF(NAME, ADDR_MSB, DATA_MSB) \
 typedef struct { \
        logic [ADDR_MSB``:0] address; \
        logic [DATA_MSB:0] data; \
    } `SIMPLE_STRUCT(NAME)
```

Then, in some place in your code, you can define the structure(s) you need:

```
`SIMPLE_STRUCT_DEF(narrow, 7, 31)
`SIMPLE_STRUCT_DEF(wide, 15, 63)
```

And, then use it wherever you need it, using only the name:

```
`SIMPLE_STRUCT(narrow) narrow1, narrow2;
narrow1.data = 0;
narrow2 = narrow1;
...
```

Comment: The purpose of using packages is to avoid those ugly Verilog structures with `define ìnclude ifdef ... and other preprocessor commands that comes from early ages of the language.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I agree. That's a missing feature of packages.

Just spitballin' here, but you could abstract your parameters into a secod package and use the right one at compile-time to tweak your package. I know that's not what you really want, but it might get you close.

I think I would just end up with multiple packages representing each configuration if I faced this in my project.

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple of thoughts.  First, I would lean towards modeling my data using classes instead of structs.  Classes can be parameterized, dynamically allocated, randomized, contain covergroups, etc.  I only use structs when I want a packed struct.  Packed structs are wonderful because you can assign to them like a regular vector and then access the data using the named fields.  Very nice. :)

Second, even if it were possible to redefine package parameters, there is only one "instance" of a package in a simulation; there can't be multiple specializations with different parameter values like there can be for modules or classes.  So it seems to me that doing away with the parameter and using a macro instead is a workable solution.  Although I don't like using macros, that would allow you to recompile with new values without changing the source code.

Comment: Fair enough, but I was more interested in design code rather than testbench code, and to date classes are not synthesizable.

Comment: Also related to the macro comment, I don't see how this really changes anything.  Using either macros or parameters you can modify the code to redefine or change the value at the compile time.  In fact for parameters this value change can be deferred to elaboration time which is a little more flexible.  Either way though makes for confusing code since the value used would be non-obvious to a reviewer.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not apply, depending on exactly what you have in mind to put in the package, but interfaces can be parameterized and are synthesizable if your tool supports it.

There is an example at http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/interfaces/

Comment: This should be a good workaround, but the spec has some inconsistencies.  In the interface section there is a sample that shows access to types in an interface by hierarchical name like my_ifc.inner_type.  However the syntax doesn't support this - look at the def of data_type and type_identifier in the syntax; type_identifier is a simple name (driven by how type resolution is handled). I think synopsys may have allowed this but cadence did not as of about a year ago on the latter.  So use carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and a coworker suggested the following:

//defines.sv:

```
`ifndef MY_DEFINES
  `define MY_DEFINES
     `define TYPEDEF_VECTOR_T typedef logic [WIDTH-1:0] vector_t;
`endif
```

//mod_sub.sv:

```
`include "defines.sv"
module mod_sub #(parameter WIDTH = 32);
...
   `TYPEDEF_VECTOR_T
   vector_t some_reg;
...
endmodule
```

//mod_top.sv:

```
module mod_top;

   mod_sub #(.WIDTH(8))  mod_sub8;
   mod_sub #(.WIDTH(64)) mod_sub64;

endmodule
```

I believe System Verilog packages are elaborated before any modules thus their contents cannot be modified by parameters at compile time.

Comment: The purpose of using packages is to avoid those ugly Verilog structures with `define ìnclude ifdef ... and other preprocessor commands that comes from early ages of the language.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a missing feature. What you're trying to do has been done with macros in Verilog for decades. Trouble is you've got to be rather unique in the way you name things to avoid clashes between packages. It's not nice, but it works.

Parameters are a bit different. They are for customising on an instance by instance basis (like VHDL generics). Either on modules for logic, or classes for test-benches. My only criticism of them is once you start using them they tend to propagate throughout your hierarchy, and the syntax isn't exactly compact. Very powerful though, and great for code re-use.

Comment: The issue here is related to parameterized types that are used in different areas of the same design.  You can do them as I showed above, or you could use `defines but neither works when different areas in the design require different param values for the same type (e.g. like a different address width).  In theory you could use `define and remember to reset or undef after the compilation unit, but relying on that is asking for trouble in my experience.

Comment: This definitely is a missing feature!  Adding capabilities into the language that used to only be possible with pretty horrific macro abuse (for example type parameters) is gradually making HDLs usable... Now if only tool vendors actually supported some of these features ;)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old post, but I don't think the situation has changed.

What I like doing these days is to auto-generate the packages through a python-based generator (peakRDL, Cogapp, custom...) which take their input from a JSON-formatted file, which acts as a device tree. (or SystemRDL which is the Accelera standard to specify registers).

That way I can generate as many flavors of the package (in the same design, or for different runs) as I want.